# Saving image in PictureBox, getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

Using Visual Studio C#. I want to save the image inside my PictureBox as a .png using SaveFileDialog, but whenever I try to, I keep getting NullReferenceException at the last line. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this and how to fix it.

```
private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "PNG(*.PNG)|*.png";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            pictureBox.Image.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Comment: check this if has a value or not ` pictureBox.Image`

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Looks like pictureBox.Image has no value. I used Graphics.DrawImage to draw onto the picture box in another method. How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score -1):

The reason that you're getting a NullReferenceException is because `pictureBox.Image.Save(...)` is actually trying to use the image in the picture box to save to your computer, but there is no image in the picturebox to save, resulting in the error.

What I think you're trying to accomplish is putting the image inside the picturebox. And if that's the case, I'd recommend using the following:

```
private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = @"PNG(*.PNG)|*.png" };

    if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(fd.FileName);
}
```

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be nice.